# How can i resolve GNU GRUB version 2.06 starting error

Tags: grub2, error-handling, versions, gnu-screen

My lenovo laptop didn't open after trying restarting. Am not well enough to use laptop, so i know nothing about it. So anyone know about it please help me to resolve the problem [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P2bUz.jpg)as soon as possible

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running, and the model of the Lenovo laptop that you're using, as this information will help others in the future with similar issues. Thanks